# Wordpress items catalogue plugin

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins, catalog

Could you please recommend a plugin for Wordpress or maybe a tiny standalone PHP script that allows the user to add some items with text info and a photo to a database, XML or just a text file from a special admin page? I need to fetch these items from the source and show in the page some way. To understand the task better, please check [this page](http://treaky.com/denis/products-classiccare.html). There is a main area that shows items but now it's just dummy HTML to see how it should look in the end.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmo,

WordPress 3.0 will support custom post types. You could [create a post type](http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/) of "Product" with custom fields (price, availability, etc.), and create a theme that displays products in an intelligent way. WP3 is currently in [Beta 2](http://wordpress.org/development/2010/05/wordpress-3-0-beta-2/), but it's a reasonably safe bet that 3.0 will be finished before you're done implementing and testing.

Hope this helps.

**Update:** WordPress 3.0 was [released on 17 June 2010](http://wordpress.org/news/2010/06/thelonious/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable setting up your own custom post type I have made a plugin that lets you manage a catalog of items to show on your WordPress pages and posts. The plugin is named CataBlog and you can check out more about it at http://catablog.illproductions.com. Good luck and hope to see you over at the blog.

Zach